# DIRing folders in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Now that in Powershell `dir` is just an alias to `Get-ChildItem`, how can I get a list of *just* folders?

I've been doing `dir /ad` (for Attribute Directory) in the command prompt for about 20 years. Is there any way to alias this with parameters in PowerShell?

I see [How do I get only directories using Get-ChildItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3085524/69683) over on Stack Overflow but I'm not going to type `Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer }` *by hand* every time. Ideally I'd like `dir /ad` to alias to that command.

Comment: Run `cmd /c dir /ad`?

Comment: @Zoredache - That... is not too bad. I tried doing `&dir` but didn't think of doing `cmd /c`

Comment: I don't believe you can alias anything to `dir /ad` or anything with arguments, but you can certainly alias it to `dir-ad` or `dirad` or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a function like this in your profile:

```
 function d([string]$switch)
 {
     if ($switch -eq "d")
     {
         Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer }
     }
     elseif ($switch -eq "f")
     {
         Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ?{ !$_.PSIsContainer }
     }
     else
     {
         Get-ChildItem -Recurse
     }
 }
```

then just use

```
d d
```

You cannot use parameters on aliases, but functions work just the same way. You get use `d -d` rather than just `d d`, or you could make directory the default and use just `d`, the possibilities are endless. You could also pass in the path.

Comment: This is a good idea if you log in to the same machine a lot.

Answer (score 3):

> how can I get a list of just folders?

`gci -d` is only seven keystrokes counting Enter... and is there waiting for you, if you're willing to upgrade your Powershell to v3 or better. :)

`gci -d -r` if you want recursion.

Edit: Removed the tab keystrokes because they are not necessary.

Comment: This is a PS v4 feature is it?

Comment: PS 3 added the `-Directory` and `-File` parameters to have `Get-ChildItem` return only directories or files, respectively.

Comment: Ok, cool. I have no intention of upgrading PS on these machines, but I do have some Server 2012 R2 and Windows 8.1 machines that I can use that command on. Good to know :)

Comment: You can also use `ls -di -r`. Powershell understands.